# How to continue read content in ListView after bottom swipe?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe, swiperefreshlayout

I have used SwipyRefreshLayout from [here](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout), because I need update data when ListView is over and continue reading content after downloading. But I have some problem - after bottom swipe focus of the application is going to ListView top. I have endless posts in ListView, so I need continue reading after downloading them. What I should change for this? Can you help me?

This is code of the application

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.activity_main;
    private static final String URL = "http://killpls.me";
    private static final String URL_MODERATION = "http://killpls.me/moderation/";

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SwipyRefreshLayout mSwipyRefreshLayout;

    private NewPostsAsyncTask newPostsAsyncTask;
    private ModerationAsyncTask moderationAsyncTask;

    public Elements content;
    public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView listView;

    private int navigationDrawerItemId;
    private boolean isRefreshed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(LAYOUT);

        initToolbar();
        initNavigationView();
        initActionBarDrawerToggle(); // Добавляет возможность открыть NavigationDrawer через значок
        initFloatingActionButton();
        initSwipeRefreshLayout();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void initNavigationView() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void initActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    private void initFloatingActionButton() {
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initSwipeRefreshLayout() {
        mSwipyRefreshLayout = (SwipyRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipyrefreshlayout);
        mSwipyRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipyRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        navigationDrawerItemId = item.getItemId();

        if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.new_posts) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Новые\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            isRefreshed = false;
            newPostsAsyncTask = new NewPostsAsyncTask();
            newPostsAsyncTask.execute();
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.moderation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Модерация\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            isRefreshed = false;
            moderationAsyncTask = new ModerationAsyncTask();
            moderationAsyncTask.execute();
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.tell_story) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Рассказать историю\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.most_terrible_stories) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Самые страшные\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.random_story) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Случайная\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.happy_end) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Happy end\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.about_project) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"О проекте\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.help_all) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Выбрано раздел \"Хочу помочь всем\" в Navigation Drawer");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, titleList);
            if (!adapter.isEmpty()) adapter.clear();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh(SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection direction) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.new_posts) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Новые\" в Navigation Drawer");
                    isRefreshed = true;
                    newPostsAsyncTask = new NewPostsAsyncTask();
                    newPostsAsyncTask.execute();
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.moderation) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Модерация\" в Navigation Drawer");
                    isRefreshed = true;
                    moderationAsyncTask = new ModerationAsyncTask();
                    moderationAsyncTask.execute();
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.tell_story) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Рассказать историю\" в Navigation Drawer");
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.most_terrible_stories) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Самые страшные\" в Navigation Drawer");
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.random_story) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Случайная\" в Navigation Drawer");
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.happy_end) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Happy end\" в Navigation Drawer");
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.about_project) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"О проекте\" в Navigation Drawer");
                } else if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.help_all) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Обновленно раздел \"Хочу помочь всем\" в Navigation Drawer");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Попытка обновить главную страницу");
                }

                // Когда обновление закончено, вызываем метод setRefreshing(boolean) и передаем ему false.
                mSwipyRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

    class NewPostsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (!isRefreshed) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setTitle("Новые");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); // Считываем заголовок страницы

                // Получение номера страницы селектором и преобразование его в число
                Elements pageSpan = doc.select("div.paginator > span:first-child");
                int pageCount = Integer.parseInt(pageSpan.first().text());
                // Стоит еще проверить, что элементы нашлись, вызовом !pageSpan.isEmpty(),
                // first() для пустого списка возвращает null.

                for (int i = pageCount; i > 0; i--) {
                    String pageCountString = Integer.toString(i);
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://killpls.me/page/" + pageCountString).get();
                    parseDocument(doc);
                    if (i == 1697) {
                        break; // Ограничение до 1697 страницы, чтобы не лагало. Надо исправить.
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Если не получилось считать
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void parseDocument(Document doc) {

            // Парсит посты на странице
            content = doc.select("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");

            for (Element contents : content) {
                if (!contents.text().contains("18+")) {
                    // Выводит только посты без ссылки на 18+
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.new_posts) progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    class ModerationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (!isRefreshed) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setTitle("Модерация");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_MODERATION).get();
                parseDocument(doc);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void parseDocument(Document doc) {

            // Парсит посты на странице
            content = doc.select("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");

            for (Element contents : content) {
                titleList.add(contents.text());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.moderation) progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the code:

```
ModerationAsyncTask

protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.new_posts)
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

After AsyncTask executed, you reset listView's adapter which would make all date of listView invalidated. That's totally a new dataset to the listView whatever it contained really. All the information of items(like position) were lost Because of adapter is changed.

Consider of using ArraryAdater.notifyDataSetChanged() when date of the adapter is changed.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used it like:
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (navigationDrawerItemId == R.id.moderation)progressDialog.dismiss();
All data is updating, but the main problem is not solved...application focus is going to ListView top after updating in ListView bottom.

Comment: Try to use setAdapter once at beginning. Just use notifyDataSetChanged when the date was changed.